# using backward slashes it takes entire path

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, kendo-ui

- I am trying to pass the path of file and get the filename alone in my grid.
- right now its working for forward slashes but its not working for backward slashes.
- when I give whole path using backward slashes it takes entire path
- can you guys tell me how to fix it.
- providing my code below

**working scenario test/player.txt
not working scenario test\player.txt**

http://jsfiddle.net/besnpj54/8/

```
        template: "<a onclick=\"window.open('#= FileName#', 'popup', 'width=800,height=600,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no')\">#= FileName.substring(FileName.lastIndexOf('/')+1) #</a>"
```

Comment: I think you want to use back ticks as part of like es7 to escape string templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to replace all the `\` with `/` before adding it into the grid. Just like this:

```
$("#save").click(function(){
      grid.dataSource.add({"FileName":$("#fname").val().replace(/\\/g,"/"),"LastName":"Last Name"});
      $("#fname").val('');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/besnpj54/11/

Please note that the `\` is used to escape special characters (as you did with the `\"`), so to get a `\` you have actually to type `\\`. For more information look at the **Special Characters** block on this page: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp

Comment: hey its working but can you tell me how you fixed it...so that I can learn

Comment: Your code was working fine with / but not with \, so at this point you have different ways to fix it. You could improve the function that adds the filename to detect either / or \ (in the line 33 of your jsfiddle). Or as I did, you can replace the \ with / before calling the funcion kendoGrid(). The trick is done in here: $("#fname").val().replace(/\\/g,"/")

Comment: can you help me with this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45269041/zone-js-140-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-remove